# Updating already implemented D3 visualizetion to new version of D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I just started learning D3. The code in the following link uses d3.v3.min: https://gist.github.com/asielen/d15a4f16fa618273e10f. I am trying to update the code and it components to d3.v6.min so that I can get myself familiar with D3.

Somehow, I could not get the plot running. My questions are:

1. **is it possible to update a code that is written in earlier version of d3.js to a newer version?**
2. If no, am I supposed to stick to the examples of the version that I will use in my implementations?

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@ssiegmund/violin-plot-playground - lots of v6 example material